# How notify DataGrid binded to ObservableCollection immediately when item is added inside "for" loop?

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, observablecollection

Suppose I have this data grid:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="MyGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding MyObservableList}"></DataGrid>
```

Suppose I have this Loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  MyObservableList.Add(i.ToString());
  Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
  Thread.Sleep(500);
}
```

Is possible to change the wpf list **immediately** after the item is inserted? Like "Console.Write" code? I tried lots of stuff like implementing "CollectionChanged" or "INotifyPropertyChanged" but they only update the DataGrid **when the loop ends**. Note: the objective is update the DataGrid from a ObservableCollection during the loop process. Any example with any kind of observable list is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't sleep on the UI thread as it will block it from being able to update the UI. Wait asynchronously using a task:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    MyObservableList.Add(i.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
    await Task.Delay(500);
}
```